# How i can deploy an ethereum smart contract that create a contract in hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, solidity

Im trying to deploy a smart contract to hyperledger fabric (from an Ethereum smart contract). When I deploy the contract it deploys correctly but when I interact with the functions of the smart contract I get this error :

```sh
      Failed to execute transaction: Transaction processing for endorser 
      [localhost:7051]: Chaincode status Code: (500) UNKNOWN. Description: 
      failed to execute contract: call error: SHR not yet implemented at 
      Object.InvalidResponse 
      (/home/hyperledger/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/errors.js:38:16) at 
      RequestManager.send 
      (/home/hyperledger/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/requestmanager.js:61:22) 
      at Eth.send [as sendTransaction] 
      (/home/hyperledger/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/method.js:145:58) at 
      SolidityFunction.sendTransaction 
      (/home/hyperledger/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/function.js:170:26) at 
      SolidityFunction.execute 
      (/home/hyperledger/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/function.js:256:37)
```

What might be causing this?

Comment: I think its safe to say you need to provide the source code for the hyperledger contract probably as it looks like this is where the error originates from https://github.com/IBM/loyalty-points-evm-fabric/issues/12

Comment: Hi thank you my smart contract works fine in remix for example, but like i said you before I configurate my machine to work with etherium smart contract in hyperledger fabric, my code of my contract is this:

Comment: I've dropped the contract text into pastebin.com for better formatting than the above URL. https://pastebin.com/hXFh0mqk

Comment: thank you Rob I keep trying to do this but I can't make it

Comment: https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FABCE-69 Do the links over here help at all? Looks like permissions need providing to enable contract calls from contracts

Comment: Thank you Rob it seems it works, but now I get another error I try to find what it is, I'II update the error if you could help me. I'll be grateful